# How can I bind Image control to ListBox dynamically?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I want to implement a ListBox which each item include a Image control and some other controls, then use it to binding some data. Due to this ListBox need to contains more than 2000 items, this means I have to do some optimization for it.

First, I noticed that most of the Image controls has one same picture(Default avatar), so I create a singleton ImageSource-object for the data. But although the Image control's source is the same object, you know I also need to create 2000 Image control in the ListBox with DataTemplate below:

```
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Avatar}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Is there have a way to reduce Image control object's number in my program? Thank you!

Comment: If the ListBox is virtualized, which it is by default, then only the visible images will be created.

Comment: 2000 maybe isn't as big a number as you think. Do you have any profiling results, or at least complaints about the program being slow to back up your need for optimization?